# Sort multiple values in hashtable in powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, hashtable, trim

I have a hashtable in PowerShell that looks like this:

```
Profil = @{
"Jason" = "P2, P4, P1";
"Mick" = "P1";
"Rocky" = "P4, P5";
"Natasha" = "P9, P4, P1"
}
```

I need to remove whitespace and sort like :

```
Profil = @{
"Jason" = "P1,P2,P4";
"Mick" = "P1";
"Rocky" = "P4,P5";
"Natasha" = "P1,P4,P9"
}
```

I try `foreach($value in $Profil.GetEnumerator() | Sort Value) {$value.Value}` but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$newProfil = @{}
$Profil.GetEnumerator() | foreach {

    $newValue = (($_.Value -replace "\s","") -split ',' | Sort-Object) -join ','
    $newProfil.add($_.Key, $newValue)
}

$newProfil
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$Profil = @{
    "Jason" = "P2, P4, P1"
    "Mick" = "P1"
    "Rocky" = "P4, P5"
    "Natasha" = "P9, P4, P1"
}

# Create an empty Hashtable with a capacity equal or greater than the number of
# elements in $Profil
$ProfilSorted = [Hashtable]::New($Profil.Count)

foreach ($KeyAndValue in $Profil.GetEnumerator())
{
    # RegEx split on a comma followed by whitespace.
    [String[]]$Value = $KeyAndValue.Value -split ',\s*' |
        Sort-Object

    # Convert $Value from array of Strings to single String joined by commas.
    [String]$Value = $Value -join ','

    $ProfilSorted.Add($KeyAndValue.Key, $Value)
}

$Profil = $ProfilSorted
$Profil
```

You may want to consider storing the value as an array of strings `[String[]]`, instead of relying on text-splicing.

Comment: Thanks for this comment ! It's very helpful !

Answer (score 2):

The following **updates the hash table in place** using a **`foreach` *statement*** (I've replaced `$Profil` with `$hash`, to avoid confusion with the automatic `$PROFILE` variable.)

```
foreach ($key in @($hash.Keys)) {
  $hash[$key] = ($hash[$key] -split ', *' | Sort-Object) -join ','
}

$hash # output the updated hash table
```

- `$hash.Keys` enumerates the hashtable's keys for use in the loop.

  - Note the `@(...)` around it, which is necessary to effectively clone the `.Keys` collection so that updating the hashtable inside the loop is permitted.
- `$hash[$key]` inside the loop accesses a single entry for the key at hand.

  - Note that PowerShell alternatively allows dot notation (`.`) to access hash-table entries as if they were properties, and generally allows variable references and expressions to specify a property name, so `$hash.key` would work too.
- `-split ', *'` splits the existing entry value into tokens by commas followed by zero or more (`*`) spaces.
- `| Sort-Object` sorts the resulting tokens.
- `-join ','` joins the sorted tokens with a comma as the separator.

---

**Using the *pipeline*** is also an option, but will generally be *slower* (though that may not matter in many use cases):

```
@($hash.Keys) | ForEach-Object {$hash[$_]= ($hash[$_] -split ', *' | Sort-Object) -join ','}
```